# Nativescript builds old code

Tags: android, nativescript

I have angular 2 nativescript project and I use

`tns livesync android --watch` or `tns run android`

to see changes on both real device and emulator. It usually works fine but at some point it starts building and syncing old code and throws JS errors based on that code.

It's usually solvable by reseting the whole project (remove platforms, node-modules, hooks) and `tns install` everything back. 
When I add new node modules and/or new custom components, I usually kill the lifesync and do the `tns build android`. 
Regardless of this lifewatch serves old html and old js (transpiled from ts).

When I saw the output in the terminal I copied out the elements that caused an error and searched in the whole project for these elements. However they are nowhere to be found. First I thought they were still inside `platforms` folder, but no, so they must be cached somewhere. Has anyone noticed this as well? How to fix this / work around this ?

I am using Webstorm - tried invalidating cache and restart. Didn't help. Decided to switch over to Visual Studio Code, but it is doing the exact same thing. I have even deleted .gradle folder in order to  delete cached files. Didn't help.

Comment: tns --version: 2.1.1

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? Sometimes compilation not happening bites you like this.

Comment: I am, but as I mentioned, even the templates (in seperate files) are not the recent ones

Comment: I see, so it's definitely not a compilation thing. Have you tried `tns platform remove android` then `tns platform add android` then running again?

Comment: It might still be compilation thing, maybe it used previous version of transpiled js which was linked to older html file, not sure. Yes I tried removing platforms and resetting the project in every way I could think of unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is fixed in next release (unfortunately not the current 2.2). Read up on their [github](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/pull/1994) . It was indeed the CLI syncing wrong files.