# Application Resources Not Working as Image Source?

Tags: nativescript

I have a very basic layout which includes a spot for an image:

```
<Image src="{{ cIconSrc }}" />
```

At first I uploaded an image to the ./resources folder and set the source of the image as:

```
"~/resources/chrome_icon.png"
```

...which worked great. Then I read that the correct way to do it is to create several variations of the image and place them within the App_Resources folder structure for both Android and IOS.  I've done that, but when I try to switch my code so that it sets the source of the image using:

```
res://chrome_icon
```

...it is not working. I don't see the image shown on the page at all. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing? Here are a few screenshots so that you can see that I put the icon variants where they should go:

[Android folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SOla.png)

[IOS screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r64fh.png)

Comment: It almost seems as though I need to register the newly uploaded images in some way. If I just set the source of the image to "res://icon" it shows up fine, but that was an image which was included in the empty Telerik project container. (Defaulted to the Nativescript icon)

Comment: If you are using `livesync` try rebuilding the app

Comment: Yes, I am using livesync. Rebuilding didn't fix it, but if I download and install the app as a complete package the images work.  I've tried going into the application settings on my phone and wiping the data for both the Telerik Platform Companion app and the NativeScript app, but no dice.

Comment: Did you try  reinstalling the app ?

Comment: Also i noticed you are using a binding how are you setting the value of the binding ?

Comment: The installed version of my app works fine, it's the uninstalled livesync version which runs inside of the NativeScript container that's failing. Are you saying I should reinstall the NativeScript app and/or the Telerik companion app?

Comment: Are you using the platform or are you running the app from your local station ? I had similair problem with livesync, have a look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853359/nativescript-builds-old-code)